# Regex: URL Encoding strange characters

Tags: regex

I have been given a Regex to work with that validates telephone numbers. The problem is that Regex has parts URL Encoded.

```
^([file://(%3f/+%3f%5b0-9%5d*/)%3f)%3f%5b0-9/-]\\(?\\+?[0-9]*\\)?)?[0-9\\- [file://(/)%5d%7b10,%7d%3f(%5bext%5d+%3f%5b0-9%5d%7b3,%7d)%3f$]\\(\\)]{10,}?([ext]+?[0-9]{3,})?$
```

I tried to make sense of it and wasn't sure if I needed to decode those URL Encoded bits, but I tried and got this

```
^([file://(?/+?[0-9]*/)?)?[0-9/-]\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9\- [file://(/)]{10,}?([ext%5d+?[0-9]{3,})?$]\(\)]{10,}?([ext]+?[0-9]{3,})?$
```

But this one is not validating of course having an opening `[` that doesn't close and other weird things.
So maybe it's the programing language that they are using that treats this differently?

Comment: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ - 
result: 
`^([file://(?/ ?[0-9]*/)?)?[0-9/-]\\(?\\ ?[0-9]*\\)?)?[0-9\\- [file://(/)]{10,}?([ext] ?[0-9]{3,})?$]\\(\\)]{10,}?([ext] ?[0-9]{3,})?$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while I managed to make it work.

```
^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9\- \(\)]{10,}?([ext]+?[0-9]{3,})?$
```

It seems that it's the email of the sender that messed up the characters and inserted crazy things in there.